# SQL to Get Data Other User Data from Same Group

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the SQL I need to pull data about other users that belong to the same group as the logged in user in my PHP application.

The data structure looks like this:

### User Table

- user_id
- name
- status
- bio

### Group Table

- group_name
- user_id

What I'm trying to do is create a page that shows the bios for all of the other members of the same group or groups that a user belongs to.

I've tried this SQL:

```
SELECT list.listname, list.user_id, list.groupname 
FROM list 
LEFT JOIN user_group ON list.user_id = user_group.user_id 
WHERE user_group.user_id = 'test@testuser.com' 
ORDER BY list.groupname
```

But I just get back the bio for `test@testuser.com`, and no other bios. If I remove the `WHERE` portion of the statement, I get all bios for all users, and not just the bios of users that are in the same group as my `test@testuser.com`. The logged in user *may* belong to more than one group.

Any ideas about how to grab this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the groups for a given user:

```
SELECT l.groupname
FROM list l 
WHERE l.user_id = 'test@testuser.com'
ORDER BY l.groupname;
```

If you want *all* users in the groups

```
SELECT l.listname, l.user_id, l.groupname
FROM list l LEFT JOIN
     user_group ug
     ON l.user_id = ug.user_id 
WHERE l.groupname IN (SELECT l2.groupname
                      FROM list l2 
                      WHERE l2.user_id = 'test@testuser.com'
                     )
ORDER BY l.groupname;
```

Comment: @sorak . . . Let me emphasize that I do not think that you "improved" the formatting of my answer.  You can read about how I format in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel, Second Edition".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by self-joining the `list` table:

```
SELECT l.listname, l.user_id, l.groupname
FROM list l
LEFT JOIN user_group ug ON l.user_id = ug.user_id 
INNER JOIN list l2 ON l2.groupname = l.groupname
                  AND l2.user_id = 'test@testuser.com'
ORDER BY l.groupname;
```

Comment: When testing this SQL in PHPMyAdmin, I'm getting a lot of syntax errors back, starting with unrecognized keyword near 'list' (before l2).

Comment: Oops! Yes, the keyword `FROM` was a copy/paste mistake. Try it now. It gives you the exact same results as Gordon's answer, but using a self-join instead of a subquery, which is generally better. Usually Gordon gives answers using joins, but I don't know why he didn't this time, so I did.